# A java program that searches for a specific color/RGB value in a 4x4 area on screen

Tags: java, colors, getcolor

I've only been able to find a way to check if a single pixel is a certain color on the specific screen coordinate with this:

```
Color color = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);

red=color.getRed();

green=color.getGreen();

blue=color.getBlue();

if(red>230 && green<100 && blue<100)
{
System.out.print("Found red color!");
}
```

I would like to know how to do that same thing but on a larger scale and in a specific area since the circle would be moving around in the area.

So an example: if there's a red circle rolling around on the top middle of the screen (inside the rectangle area xy to xy) it would know that it showed up and print out in the cmd window "Found red color!".

Comment: You can use for loops to vary x and y.

Comment: @tgdavies I've also thought about doing that but what would be a good way to do that? Something that might not have been obvious enough is that this would be inside a loop already but it's only one pixel, I want it to be on a larger scale so that it could cover about 400 by 300 pixels (horisontal rectangle area).